# Functionality to treat floating tabs as separate from main window

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock, xceed

Context: I launch my main window. Within that window I create three new tabs. I float two of the tabs and leave the other within the main window. There are two problems I am currently trying to tackle:

1. I want to be able to minimize the main window without hiding my other floating tabs as well.
2. When shifting focus to another program (e.g. Chrome) then clicking back on my floating tab, I don't want all my other floating tabs + the main window to be brought back to front, in effect hiding my other program.

I believe this should be possible since the Visual Studio UI is built using WPF and I can achieve this functionality using floating tabs in VS.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. What have you investigated/tried so far for example.

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything online so did not know exactly where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. The reason why it is being minimized is because the default owner of the floating window is the main window. so you have to set the `floatingWindow.Owner = null;` then you will also be able to put the main window in front of the floating window. if you want to switch between floating window and main window you can set `floatingWindow.ShowInTaskbar = true;`.

In my code i put it in a selectionChanged event handler so when i pop out a document it fires the selectionChanged event.

Document creation

```
 private void userItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutDocument ld = new LayoutDocument();
        ld.Title = "All Users";
        ld.ToolTip = "Manage all users";
        //selection changed event
        ld.IsSelectedChanged += Ld_IsSelectedChanged;
        ld.IsActiveChanged += Ld_IsSelectedChanged;
        Users users = new Users(ld);
        ld.Content = users;
        LayoutDocumentPane pane = ((todaysPayments.FindParent<LayoutDocumentPane>() ?? (panal.Children?[0] as LayoutDocumentPane)) ?? new LayoutDocumentPane());
        pane.Children.Add(ld);
        if (panal.ChildrenCount == 0)
        {
            panal.Children.Add(pane);
        }
        ld.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

And the event handler

```
public void Ld_IsSelectedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the floating windows from the DockingManager
        manager.FloatingWindows.ToList().ForEach(floatingWindow =>
        {
            floatingWindow.Owner = null;
            floatingWindow.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            var fw = floatingWindow.Model as LayoutDocumentFloatingWindow;
            floatingWindow.Title = fw?.RootDocument?.Title ?? "";
        });
    }
```